# Load real map into Gaea with textures

Tags: gaea

I try to create a map from real world data in the terrain design application [Gaea](https://quadspinner.com/).

So I wen't to [this site](https://heightmap.skydark.pl/) and switched to sattelite view. Then I choosed the area I like and download the heightmap and the texture.

Next I added a "File" node and loaded the heightmap into it:

[image]

How can I load the texture?